# How to add multiple set of value in a same node for same User?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using realtime database. In that multiple users will give same set of data like shown in Snapshot1. Whenever the same user submitting other set of data, it is updating the old record but I want to add as a new record like a single user can save multiple set of data like in Snapshot2.

My Code is:

```
   Contribution cont = new Contribution(money, month, payment, date, tref, rem);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Contribution")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .setValue(cont).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ContributionDeclarationForm.this, "Successfully Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ContributionDeclarationForm.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ContributionDeclarationForm.this, "Not Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Snapshot1:

[image: Snapshot1]

Snapshot2:

[image: Snapshot2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, you can simply use DatabaseReference's [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method, which:

> Creates a reference to an auto-generated child location.

So something like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Contribution")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .push().setValue(cont).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    ...
```

This means that you'll get a unique key for each child under (Contribution/$uid). So your new schema will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Contribution
        |
        --- $uid
             |
             --- $pushedId
                    |
                    --- Amount: "369"
                    |
                    --- Contribution_Month: "5-2025"
                    |
                    --- //Other properties
```

If you want to get all children of a single user, you need to use a reference that points to the UID and loop through the results like in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Contribution").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String amount = task.getResult().child("Amount").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", amount);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be the "amount" of each child that exists under the above reference.

If you need numbers, it's best to store them in the database as numbers and **not** as String values.

Comment: Hi Alex Thanks for Your Answer, my query is like if i insert a value it needs to check with that node if any data exists it shouldn't update it. it should create another set.

Comment: Your initial question is about setting/adding different objects under the same node, while the question in the comment is about checking the existence of a node and an update, which are totally different things. At a first glance, if you need to check something first, you need to create a Query, but that should be considered another question. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Final Output]

For this i got a solution and my solution is:

```
// Declared in globally
DatabaseReference ref;
Contribution cont;
//declared inside a method
cont = new Contribution();
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Contribution")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        cont.setAmount(money);
        cont.setContribution_Month(month);
        cont.setMode_Of_Payment(payment);
        cont.setTransaction_Date(date);
        cont.setTransaction_RefNo(tref);
        cont.setRemarks(rem);

        ref.child(month).push().setValue(cont);
        Toast.makeText(ContributionDeclarationFormActivity.this, "Successfully Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ContributionDeclarationFormActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```